# String vector input and query operation

Tags: c++, string, vector

In my C++ code, I acquire a user-defined number of input strings. Next the user enters a user-defined number of query strings. For each query string, I want to output the number of its instances, in the collection of strings originally input by the user.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    int N, Q;
    cout << "Enter number of strings : ";
    cin >> N;
    vector <string> strInp(N);
    string sbuf;

    // Storing the strings in the vector
    cout << "Enter the strings:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> sbuf;
        strInp.push_back(sbuf);
    }

    // Storing the queries
    cout << "Enter the number of queries : ";
    cin >> Q;

    vector <string> query(Q);
    string qbuf;
    cout<<" Enter the query strings"<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++) {
        cin >> qbuf;
        query.push_back(qbuf);
    }

    // Counting the instances of the query strings
    // Initializing the instances vector
    vector <int> instances;

    string s1, s2;
    int flag = 0;   

    vector <string> ::iterator start1 = query.begin();
    vector <string> ::iterator end1 = query.end();

    vector <string> ::iterator start2 = strInp.begin();
    vector <string> ::iterator end2 = strInp.end();

    for (auto i = start1; i < end1; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    s1 = *i;
    for (auto j = start2; j < end2; j++) {
        s2 = *j;
        if (s1 == s2) {
            count++;
        }           
    }
    instances.push_back(count);
    }

    cout << "The number of instances of each query are : " << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < instances.size(); i++) {
        cout << instances[i] << endl;
    }



    return 0;
    _getch();
}
```

On running the code, I have the following output

```
Enter the number of inputs : 5
Enter the strings:
apple
apple
apple
ball
cat

Enter the number of queries: 3
Enter the query strings:
apple
ball
cat

The number of instances of each query are :
5
5
5
3
1
1
```

The expected output is actually :

```
The number of instances of each query are :
3
1
1
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can point out what I am doing wrong?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating a `std::vector` with the constructor that takes a count, then you already fill in that amount of elements.

So for your example that means `strInp` is `{"","","","","","apple","apple","apple","ball","cat"}`
and `query` is `{"","","","apple","ball","cat"}`

So you need to either write to those elements or create an empty vector and use push_back.

So it's 
`vector <string> strInp(N);` and `vector <string> query(Q);`
with 
`strInp[i]=sbuf;` and `query[i]=qbuf;`

or it's

`vector <string> strInp;` and `vector <string> query;`
with 
`strInp.push_back(sbuf);` and `query.push_back(qbuf);`